# API key vs. Access Token

Tags: php, curl, paypal

[Paypal Adaptive Payments Intro](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/adaptive-payments/integration-guide/APIntro/)

[Paypal API intro](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/integration/direct/make-your-first-call/)

What is the difference is between an API key and an Access Token? They both seem to work as "passwords" for the paypal communications.

I'm running the code on the paypal API intro(using curl in PHP, which I'm also just starting to understand), and I'm not sure how to get from that the the paypal adaptive payments stuff. I'm having trouble figuring out how I call "Adaptive Payments" in my code. Do I actually put that in there somewhere or is it implied when I call for multiple payments with one transaction?

Comment: API Keys are for Applications, Access Tokens are for Users.  Your Application, using your API Key asks a user to verify that you grant privileges to access their account.  In tern PayPal gives you an Access Token for the specific user so you can access their account with out their password moving forward.  This token can be revoked by the user at any time thus turning off access for your application.

Comment: Okay, on the "API intro" I use the app ID and secret to get the Access Token. Why don't I use their paypal username/email if it is meant to identify them?

Comment: Because before paypal gives you the token the user must be logged into paypal and then verify that they want to give you access to their account. This completely takes you out of the equation and limits your ability to spoof a customer or make off with any sensitive information. The token you are given is specific to your application, whereas the user's email address is specific to the user. Paypal/the user can't revoke the user's email, but they can revoke your access token.

Comment: Where does the token come into play on this diagram?https://www.paypalobjects.com/webstatic/en_US/developer/docs/ap/AdapPymntSrvcFlow_A.gif Because, if they are on paypal when they input their info, then I don't understand why I need the access token.  Also, could someone direct me to the documentation for how to make a "pay" request? I can't find it in the REST API reference.

Comment: As I understand it:
1) My App identifies itself with it's username/ID and password/secret, and sends info about the payment.
2) It gets "logged in" with an identifying code proving it's legitimacy, and all the info that was sent with the ID and secret are packaged with that.
3) The user is then sent to paypal, where the paykey references their database, getting the info I sent with the ID and secret using the Pay key.
4) The user logs into their paypal, confirms payment, and then gets sent back to my website.

So I don't get where the user token comes in.